# Downloading of file stops due to TimeOut using Retrofit and OkHTTPClient

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

I am using Retrofit to download files but after few seconds downloading stops by giving this error "**retrofit give Thread suspension timed out: 110 during download**" or mostly "**JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 2840) ,**" , how to resolve this issue? File could be of any size 5MB,10MB and time of downloading could be any depending upon internet speed. Downloading shouldn't stop in case of latency.

Code :

```
public void run() {

        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addNetworkInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                    @Override
                    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                      try {
                          Response originalResponse = chain.proceed(chain.request());
                          return originalResponse.newBuilder()
                                  .body(new ProgressResponseBody(originalResponse.body(), progressListener))
                                  .build();
                      }
                      catch (Exception e) {
                             e.printStackTrace();
                          progressListener.onError(e.getCause()+": "+e.getMessage());

                      }
                      return chain.proceed(chain.request());
                    }
                });
        AppGlobal.Log("usm_fileUrl","baseUrl= "+BASE_URL+" ,fileName= "+fileName);
        Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                ;
        Retrofit retrofit = builder.client(httpClient.build()).build();
        RetrofitInterface downloadService = retrofit.create(RetrofitInterface.class);
        Call<ResponseBody> call = downloadService.downloadFileByUrl(fileName);
        this.notificationId = this.mNotification.createNotification(fileTitle,"Downloading...");
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, final retrofit2.Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Got the body for the file");

                    new AsyncTask<Void, Long, Void>() {
                        @Override
                        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                            saveToDisk(response.body());
                            return null;
                        }
                    }.execute();

                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Connection failed " + response.errorBody());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
                Log.e(TAG, t.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

}